# no effect of "resultpath" constant in struts.xml

Tags: struts2

I have all the jsp pages (ex: index.jsp) in the  WebContent folder and my application is working smoothly.
Now, I created a folder "pages" inside WebContent, where I transferred all my jsp pages.

And I added the following line inside the `<struts>` tags:

```
<constant name="struts.convention.result.path" value="/pages" />
```

But still, its not searching for jsp inside the "pages" folder.
I am getting:

**HTTP Status 404 - /MyApplicationName/index.jsp**

Where am I doing a mistake?

EDIT: The current structure of my application is as follows:

The welcome page is an action instead of a jsp page. The result page of this action is index.jsp. This action populates the dropdown menu and some other fields in index.jsp. Now, I want to keep index.jsp along with other jsp pages in the folder "WebContent/pages". I have over 30 jsp pages in my application, and I don't want to mention the full path of every jsp in the result-tag. Thats why I want to make use of the struts2 constant **"struts.convention.result.path"**

My question is, why the code I have mentioned above is not working?

Comment: Post your configuration details.

Comment: if you are using `Struts2-Convention-Plugin`, try `index.action`

Comment: put pages directly under /WEB-INF/content/ (no "struts.convention.result.path" needed or at least "/WEB-INF/pages/" to force the involvement of struts2 but then you'll need the result path set). Also you'll need to set struts2 action extension to include jsp if you really want that extension. I've not tried this... I think if you want to hide details from the users setting the action extension to html would be best. Jsp isn't a good choice because you might need to use a different view technology and it would be a bit confusing.

Comment: Show your `<welcome-file-list>` in web.xml file.

Comment: Have u solved your problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Accessing `index.jsp` directly bypasses all S2 request handling.

There's no S2 or S2 Convention plugin involved, you're just accessing a JSP page.

Answer (score 0):

If `index.jsp` is first page of your application then you need to change its path to /pages/index.jsp in `<welcome-file>` tag of web.xml. And for rest I agree with @Dave Newton :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably your mistake was in struts.xml.

When you create a `new-Folder` under `web-content` make with the same name (folder-name) of

`xml file` `under src` and include it in `struts.xml` file it will work fine.

For eg: suppose you created `example folder` under web-content, now create example.xml file

under src folder  and in struts.xml file include example.xml

> example.xml:

```
<struts>

    <package name="example" namespace="/example" extends="default">
     <action name="your action name" class="your class" method="your method">
     </action> 
</package>
</struts>
```

> struts.xml:

```
<struts>

<constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false" />
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />

<action  name="" class="" method="">
</action>
</package>

<include file="example.xml"/>
```

Comment: Thanks. By the way, its not necessary to create a folder named example. I know how to include xml files in struts.xml.
The question is, how to use the constant result.path in struts2 to make the server look for the result pages at a specific location, which is better than mentioning the full path for every result page in the result tag.